# Custom ListView in ListFragment or Fragment?

Tags: android, xml, listview, fragment

I am working on a simple app, so that the main activity has two fragments that user can swipe to go to. On one of them, I want to have custom list. For example, something like this https://github.com/JakeWharton/SwipeToDismissNOA, where each item in the list can be deleted by swiping. I was able to get a regular list to work inside the ListFragment, but can't get this custom list to work. As I understand, ListFragment needs to have a simple .xml with one , but the one that I want to use, has a bit more stuff in it. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:padding="16dp">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:text="ListView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So when I am trying to getListView() using this .xml, it either returns null or when I am trying to do something like this: 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, null);
    ListView ls = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

It throws this error: 
10-15 20:25:28.895: E/AndroidRuntime(8081): 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, is easiest work with my own IDs, so I would change your ListView ID to another one. For my example, I choose `android:id="@+id/myList"`.

In your fragment, in your `onCreateView` method, try inflating your layout and getting your view by ID.

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourDummyLayout, container, false);


        //You should get your ListView there
        ListView yourListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.myList);

        [......]

        return rootView;
    }
```

Try with this ;) Good luck !